# SuggestView фильтрация данных

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Можно ли в `yandex maps api` фильтровать данные в `SuggestView`, следующим образом

`1. Только города и населенные пункты в заданной стране.
 2. Только улицы в заданном городе
 3. Дома только на заданной улице`

Вариант дописывать `страну/город/улицу` в реквест мне категорически не нравится, а

```
let sugg = new ymaps.suggest(request).then(items => {..});  
     return sugg;
```

- все что в `then`, отрабатывает после того как `sugg` возвращен провайдером.

https://gist.github.com/iOgre/0fa06250bb3e82faa3a4277bf1d00ffa

https://github.com/iOgre/ymapsimple

https://codepen.io/iOgre/pen/vjNzWG?editors=0011

Answer (score 1):

Ограничить поисковые подсказки страной, городом или улицей можно только прямо указывая их в запросе или написав собственный провайдер подсказок.

Единственный способ ограничить поисковые подсказки - задать приоритетную область поиска через [опцию `boundedBy`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/suggest-docpage/?from=SO#param-options.boundedBy)

Comment: Мне интересно - как именно это сделать через провайдер
К сожалению - `let sugg = new ymaps.suggest(request).then(items => {..});  
     return sugg;`
сначала возвращается результат суггеста, а уже потом отрабатывает его then

Comment: поставьте return sugg; внутрь обработки then